# Why do I keep getting an implicit conversion error?

Tags: c#

I was just coding using c# in the Unity Game Engine, and I keep running into this error:

> Assets/Background/SkyManager.cs(30,29): error CS0266: Cannot
>   implicitly convert type `float' to`int'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is my code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;

public class SkyManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int hours = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours;
    public int minutes = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes;
    public int seconds = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds;
    public Light lighting;
    //public CameraClearFlags night;
    public Camera night;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        print (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //what should the rotation of light be?
        //15° every hour

        if(hours != 1){    
            int sunRotation = 7.5f * hours;
            print (sunRotation);    
        }    
        //end
        var rot = transform.rotation;           
        lighting.transform.rotation = rot * Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0);
       }   
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

On your line `int sunRotation = 7.5f * hours;`, you are using `7.5f` which is a float value. You are trying to place this in an `int` variable.

You could use the following to convert the data into an `int`.

```
int sunRotation = (int)(7.5f * hours);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code here is a returning a float:
`int sunRotation = 7.5f * hours;`

But you are trying to assign it as an integer.  You can cast the value to an integer as Juken suggested, however you're going to lose any decimal values that you may have wanted it maintain.

You should consider using Math.Ceil or Math.Floor to either round your value up or down depending on your intention, or perhaps assign the value to a float to maintain the accuracy.